# map array to elements text using jQuery.each inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

for the given html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">x</div>
    <div class="child">y</div>
    <div class="child">z</div>
</div>
```

How can I map the text of its children from an array?

This is my try:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = -1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    $('#parent .child').each(function () {
        $(this).text(myArray[i]);
    });
}
```

I get: `c,c,c`

How can I get `a,b,c` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the outer `for` loop:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$('#parent .child').each(function (index) {
    $(this).text(myArray[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `for` loop here.

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$('#parent').find('div').each(function(){
  $(this).html(myArray[$(this).index()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">x</div>
    <div class="child">y</div>
    <div class="child">z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `each` already provides an optional parameter for the callback which is the index!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I have seen it inside florian's answer. It's just an another way to solve it. And by the way - in would be unfair if I would copy&paste florian's solution.

Comment: If a better answer is already provodided then you could just step down and not answering!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I just wonder - have you to use `!` in your every sentence? Anyways, it's just less 'elegant' solution, not worse.

Comment: I didn't say worse! It's still a correct answer and a better way but not the best!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Fine. But still, the fact that my answer isn't 'the best' is a good reason to not post it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text(function)`

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$("#parent > .child").text(function(index) {
  return myArray[index]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">x</div>
  <div class="child">y</div>
  <div class="child">z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: @null Note, `.each()` is not necessary to return expected result. First parameter of `.text(function(index, existingText){})` callback is index of current element in `jQuery()` collection. `.text()` iterates each element in the collection returned by `$("#parent > .child")` call.